# How to add parameter with SOAP request?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, php-5.2.x.x

I'm new to Magento I try to call category level using Magento SOAP API with parent category id. I use following code.

```
<?php
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://domain/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $proxy->login('user', 'password');
$result = $proxy->call($session,'catalog_category.level');
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Here for the above code, "Default Category" details are coming. now I try to call some other category by using following codes.

```
$result = $proxy->call($session,'catalog_category.level',12);
```

That is not working

```
$arguments = array( 'parentCategory' => 12);
$result = $proxy->call($session,'catalog_category.level',$arguments);
```

This is also not working.

Then I try to call category tree using following code.

```
 <?php
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://domain/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $proxy->login('user', 'password');
$result = $proxy->call($session,'catalog_category.tree');
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

it showing all the category tree. it means API is working but whenever I try to pass an argument it showing server not found an error.

Can any one please tell me how to pass arguments with the request.

Comment: check [API Example Here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.level.html)

Comment: That example is without parameter. anyway thanks for trying to help me :)

Comment: you can check parameter there in doc

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
/* code to check SOAP enabled in your server or not */
echo (extension_loaded('soap'))?'SOAP Enabled':'SOAP Disabled';echo '<br />';
echo (class_exists('SOAPClient'))?'SOAP Client Present':'SOAP Client Absent';echo '<br />';
echo (class_exists('SOAPServer'))?'SOAP Server Present':'SOAP Server Absent';echo '<br />';



/** Code to authenticate SOAP credentials and authorize the request URL **/
$apiUrl = 'http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl';
$apiUser = 'yourSoapApiUser'; 
$apiKey = 'yourSoapApiKey';

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
try{
    $client = new SoapClient($apiUrl, array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
} catch (SoapFault  $e) {
    echo 'Error in Soap Connection : '.$e->getMessage();
}
try {
    $session = $client->login($apiUser, $apiKey);
    if($session){
        $params = array('storeId'=>$storeId,'categoryId'=>$categoryId);
        try {
            $result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_category.tree',$params);
            echo json_encode($result);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $result = json_encode(array('isFault' => 1, 'faultMessage'=>$e->getMessage()));
            $error = true;
        }
    }else echo 'SOAP Connection Failed.';
} catch (SoapFault  $e) {
    echo 'Wrong Soap credentials : '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

The above code worked fine for me. If it won't for you then check your corresponding Api.php method.

Gist : Multiple request params are always sent in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call it like

```
$proxy->call($sessionId, 'category.level', array(null, null, 12));
```

For more information about the function check class

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api and function `level($website = null, $store = null, $categoryId = null)`
```

If you want to pass particular website and store you can pass it instead of null parameter.

Comment: it is not working brother

Answer (score 0):

i manage to get output using soapv2. but it is slow compare to soapv1 but it is giving the required out put. the code i use to pass parameter is given as below.

```
 <?php
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://domain/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1');
$session = $proxy->login((object)array('username' => 'user', 'apiKey' => 'password'));
$result = $proxy->catalogCategoryTree((object)array('sessionId' => $session->result, 'parentId' => '12'));
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```